# Is there a way to communicate between workspaces of two Matlab Instances?

Tags: matlab

Hi I have two Matlab instances running two simulink models. I want to use the Workspace data of Matlab Instance1 in Matlab Instance 2. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The only way is to save and load .mat-files. Or consider the Parallel Computing Toolbox, so you don't need two instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got [this](https://github.com/JasonFriedman/RepeatedMeasures/tree/5c32225628d970981e6eec840fe84e71f3c1419c/matlab/msocket) work helpful in communicating with two matlab instances.

Just use 'localhost' in place of server.

Answer (score 0):

As mentined by @thewaywewalk, you can save/load .mat files as communication.

Another option is to use the Matlab COM Automation server. Depending on your application, it may be overkill, but you don't need any extra toolboxes. Here is the documentation:  [Matlab COM Automation Server](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-matlab-com-automation-server.html;jsessionid=37389e87e28935d8ca8388682a31).